# Does pressure change get changed instantaneously for far away points

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

According to Pascal's law that an application of pressure at any point would increase the pressure at all points in a confined fluid. Does that change occur instantaneously? I'm assuming no because we could use that to transfer information faster than light which would violate causality. If it doesn't then what is happening at molecular level so that pressure increase is transferred to all points?

Comment: Speed of sound in the liquid, rather than that of light.